# I need a specific output

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have to get a specific output format from my tables.

Let's say I have a simple table with 2 columns **name** and **value**.

table **T1**

```
+---------------+------------------+
| Name          | Value            |
+---------------+------------------+
| stuff1        | 1                |
| stuff1        | 1                |
| stuff2        | 2                |
| stuff3        | 1                |
| stuff2        | 4                |
| stuff2        | 2                |
| stuff3        | 4                | 
+---------------+------------------+
```

I know the values are in the interval 1-4. I group it by name and value and count number of the same rows as **Number** and get the following table:

table **T2**

```
+---------------+------------------+--------+
| Name          | Value            | Number |
+---------------+------------------+--------+
| stuff1        | 1                | 2      |
| stuff2        | 2                | 2      |
| stuff3        | 1                | 1      |
| stuff3        | 4                | 1      |
+---------------+------------------+--------+
```

**Here is the part when I need your help! What should I do if I want to get these format?**

table **T3**

```
+---------------+------------------+--------+
| Name          | Value            | Number |
+---------------+------------------+--------+
| stuff1        | 1                | 2      |
| stuff1        | 2                | 0      |
| stuff1        | 3                | 0      |
| stuff1        | 4                | 0      |
| stuff2        | 1                | 0      |
| stuff2        | 2                | 2      |
| stuff2        | 3                | 0      |
| stuff2        | 4                | 0      |
| stuff3        | 1                | 1      |
| stuff3        | 2                | 0      |
| stuff3        | 3                | 0      |
| stuff3        | 4                | 1      |
+---------------+------------------+--------+
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: I've withdrawn my answer as it gives the error pointed out by Karl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You start with a `cross join` to generate all possible combinations and then left-join in the results from your existing query:

```
select n.name, v.value, coalesce(nv.cnt, 0) as "Number"
from (select distinct name from table t) n cross join
     (select distinct value from table t) v left outer join
     (select name, value, count(*) as cnt
      from table t
      group by name, value
     ) nv
     on nv.name = n.name and nv.value = v.value;
```

Answer (score 2):

Variation on the theme.

Differences between Gordon Linoff and Owen existing answers.

1. I prefer GROUP BY to get the Names rather than a DISTINCT. This may have better performance in a case like this. (See [Rob Farley's still relevant article](http://msmvps.com/blogs/robfarley/archive/2007/03/24/group-by-v-distinct-group-by-wins.aspx).)
2. I explode the subqueries into a series of CTEs for clarity.
3. I use table T2 as the question now labels the group results set instead of showing that as as subquery.

   ```
   WITH PossibleValue AS (
     SELECT 1 Value 
      UNION ALL
     SELECT Value + 1 
   FROM PossibleValue 
      WHERE Value < 4 
   ), 
   Name AS (
     SELECT Name 
       FROM T1
      GROUP BY Name
   ),
   NameValue AS (
     SELECT Name 
           ,Value
       FROM Name
            CROSS JOIN
            PossibleValue
   )
   SELECT nv.Name
         ,nv.Value
         ,ISNULL(T2.Number,0) Number
     FROM NameValue nv
          LEFT JOIN
          T2 ON nv.Name = T2.Name
            AND nv.Value = T2.Value
   ```

Comment: I'm failing to get my SQL to show up formatted as code with the proper line breaks, etc. When I try to edit it look right in the editor, but not in the preview. That's a new one for me.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another solution, this time using a Table Value Constructor in a CTE to build a table of name value combinations.

```
WITH value AS 
( SELECT DISTINCT t.name, v.value
    FROM T1 AS t
   CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4)) AS v (value)
)
  SELECT v.name AS 'Name', v.value AS 'Value', COUNT(t.name) AS 'Number'
    FROM value AS v
    LEFT JOIN T1 AS t ON t.value = v.value AND t.name = v.name
GROUP BY v.name, v.value, t.name;
```